# Trying to Eliminate Duplicate Rows SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to do a SQL output with most updated price of product.  The product_price can be updated multiple times for the product number, therefore creating more than one row.  I'm looking to eliminate more than one row per product_number.

```
 SELECT
 product_number
 ,product_price
 ,MAX(update_timestamp)
 FROM product_price
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: can you elaborate the problem a little more?

Comment: I'm looking to eliminate more than one row per product_number

Comment: If I were your DBMS what would you call me? Scratch that you're doing an aggregate with no group by must my mySQL.

Comment: what do you mean by "eliminate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this.  My preferred is a subquery.  First get the product number and it's maxtimestamp:

```
SELECT product_number
 ,MAX(update_timestamp) as maxtimestamp
 FROM product_price
group by product_number
```

Now turn that into a subquery and inner join it to the first table to filter all but the max:

```
select a.product_number, a.maxtimestamp, b.product_price
from    ( SELECT product_number ,MAX(update_timestamp) as maxtimestamp
FROM product_price
group by product_number) a
inner join product_price b on a.product_number = b.product_number 
    and a.maxtimestamp =   b.update_timestamp
```

Comment: there are some results where the timestamp is duplicated. Is there a simple way to select just one record?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the most updated then try sticking a TOP 1 clause in it and remove the MAX: SELECT TOP 1
 product_number
 ,product_price
 ,update_timestamp
 FROM product_price
 ORDER BY 1,2

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g SQL Server,MySql)? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the last updated price *for each product*, then try this:

```
SELECT
  Ranked.product_number,
  Ranked.product_price,
  Ranked.update_timestamp
FROM
(
  SELECT
    pp.product_number,
    pp.product_price,
    pp.update_timestamp,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY pp.product_number
      ORDER BY pp.update_timestamp DESC
    ) AS TimeRank
  FROM product_price AS pp
) AS Ranked
WHERE Ranked.TimeRank = 1
```

That dense rank in the center says that within each product (PARTITION BY), rank the latest updates (update_timestamp DESC) first.  Then in the outer query, we only take the #1s (TimeRank = 1).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT
  product_number
  ,product_price
  ,update_timestamp
 FROM product_price
 ORDER BY update_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

you order by `update_timestamp` and then take the first result.

and if you want get every product its latest update time then use this

```
 SELECT 
p.*
FROM
    product_price p
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT 
          product_number, MAX(update_timestamp) AS latest
      FROM
          product_price
      GROUP BY 
          product_number
    ) AS groupedp
  ON  groupedp.product_number = p.product_number
  AND groupedp.latest = p.update_timestamp ;
```